# How does recursion works in this code to find GCD?

Tags: java, recursion

I came across this codes for finding the GCD of an array of numbers from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gcd-two-array-numbers/)

```
//Function to return gcd of a and b 
static int gcd(int a, int b) { 
    if (a == 0) {
        return b;
    }
    return gcd(b % a, a); 
} 
// Function to find gcd of array of 
// numbers 
static int findGCD(int arr[], int n) { 
    int result = arr[0]; 
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        result = gcd(arr[i], result); 
    }
    return result; 
}
```

The method `gcd` uses a recursive call `gcd(b % a, a)`. So how does this recursive call works? I know the basics of how a recursion works but I am a little confused on how the `gcd` method on this piece of code uses recursion. Can anyone please explain to me simply, how the `gcd` method works in this code?

Comment: Did you try to perform the recursion by hand on small numbers? Like `gcd(18, 4)`? This would probably help you understand how it works.

Comment: @Holt yeah but I don't really understand how the recursive call `gcd(b % a, a)` produces `2` based from the input `gcd(18, 4)` Can't you just tell me how the thing works?

Comment: @Holt based from the input `gcd(18, 4)` the `a` is `18` and the `b` is `4` . `4 mod 18` is `4` right? So how did the output became `2` ?

Comment: That's how recursion works, you start again. Just go through all the call until you meet the terminal condition. `gcd(18, 4)`, since `18 != 0`, you call `gcd(4 % 18, 18)` which gives you `gcd(4, 18)`, so you basically switch, then `4` is still not `0` so you get `gcd(18 % 4, 4)`, which is `gcd(2, 4)`, and so on, until you call `gcd(0, X)` and in this case you know that the gcd is X.

Comment: Are you having trouble with the code or the algorithm? The algorithm is [_Euclid's algorithm_ for the GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm), if you care to read up on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take two numbers 24 and 60, and you called the function as `gcd(24, 60)`, then the function stack executes as follows,

```
gcd(24,60) => 60%24 = 12
gcd(24,12) => 12%24 = 12 (Switch happens)
gcd(12,24) => 24%12 = 0
gcd(0 ,12) => terminates
```

So switch that happens at step two is the important one because the call basically swaps two numbers, just like you do in an iterative way, think of it like shorthand way.

I could take the same example with 60 and 24 as the first call, then `gcd(60,24)` would execute as

```
gcd(60,24) => 24%60 = 24 (Switch happens)
gcd(24,60) => 60%24 = 12 and this follows the same pattern as the above
```

Here the switch happens because the functions send `b%a` to the next function as `a` and `a` to the function as `b`.

Answer (score 1):

Given two numbers, 12 and 8:

gcd(12,8) calculates b%a = 12%8 = 4 and then calls gcd(4, 8). It does not return yet, because that last call is not completed yet.

gcd(4,8) calculates b%a = 8%4 = 0 and then calls gcd(0,4). That one does not return yet as well, because that call is active.

gcd(0,4) branches into the first `if`-statement and returns 4.

That defines the return value of gcd(4,8), so the pending call returns 4 as well.

That again defines the return value of gcd(12,8), so the final result is still 4.

---

The math behind it is also interesting.

I think the main question is: why can we reduce gcd(12,8) to gcd(4,8)?

We assume that there is any result g that can divide 12 without a remainder and 8 without a remainder.

We can split the 12 into g*n (4*3) and 8 into g*m (4*2).

Next, we can say 12-8 = g*n-g*m = g*(n-m)  (4*(3-2)=4). Therefore g does not only divide 12 and 8 without remainder, but also 12-8 (4).

You can do that for even lower numbers: 12-8-8 = g*n-g*m-g*m=g*(n-m-m) (4*(3-2-2)=-4). And so on.

The same is true for larger numbers: 12+8 = g*n+g*m = g*(n+m) (4*(3+2)=20). And you can repeat that by adding 8 numerous times.

The smallest positive number you can get by this approch is 12%8, because you can subtract 8 from 12 for so many times until its remainder is left.

Answer (score 1):

To help understand recursive methods it is often useful to place `print` statements in key locations so you can follow what is happening.

By calling the method with specifically chosen `prime factors`, it is easy to ensure a particular `gcd`.

In the example below, `3` is the only common factor so it will be the gcd of the two numbers.

```java
    public class RecursiveGCD {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println("GCD = " + gcd(2 * 3 * 4 * 4 * 5, 3 * 7 * 11));
       }
       public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
          System.out.println("\nFinding gcd of a=" + a + " and b=" + b);
          if (a == 0) {
             System.out.println("a == 0 so returning b (gcd) = " + b);
             return b;
          }
          System.out.println(
                "Remainder non-zero, calling with gcd(b % a,  a) = gcd(" + (b % a)
                      + ", " + a + ").");
          return gcd(b % a, a);

       }
    }
```